# ¿Como no permitir seleccionar producto de otra lista si ya se selecciono en una lista, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Buen dia.
De esta forma Selecciono producto de 2 lista

**Lista No. 1**

```
$$('.lista_productos_elegir').on('click','.sumarProducto1', function(e){
        var list = $(this).closest('.swipeout_productos1');
            var el_product_quantity_producto1 = list.find('.product-quantity');
            var tipo_material                 = list.find('.tipo_material').text();
            var tipo_costo_material           = list.find('.tipo_costo_material').text();
            var codinv_material               = list.find('.codInventario_material').text();
            var preciosocio_material          = list.find('.preciosocio_material').text();
            var volumenNegocio_material       = list.find('.volumenNegocio_material').text();
            var tipo_seleccion                = list.find('.tipo_seleccion').text();
                product_sum                   = parseInt(el_product_quantity_producto1.text());
                cantidad_suma                 = product_sum+1;
                //el_product_quantity_producto1.text(cantidad_suma);

            var cantidad_valor1 =0;
            var lista;
            $('.lista_productos_elegir li').each(function(e){
                lista = $(this).find('.product-quantity');
                cantidad_valor1 += parseInt(lista.text());
            });

            if (cantidad_valor1 >=1){
               myApp.alert("Puede llevar un máximo de 1 productos");
               el_product_quantity_producto1.text(el_product_quantity_producto1.text());
            }
            else{
                $(".lista_productos_seleccionado > tr").remove();
                productos_seleccionados = deleteItem(productos_seleccionados, codinv_material);

                 productos_seleccionados.push({
                    "codigo": codinv_material,
                    "precio": preciosocio_material,
                    "cantidad": cantidad_suma
                 })
               el_product_quantity_producto1.text(cantidad_suma);
               agregarCupon(idPedido, codinv_material, tipo_costo_material,preciosocio_material,volumenNegocio_material,cantidad_suma,cod_cliente,tipo_cliente,cod_cupon,parseInt(tipo_seleccion));
               productosSeleccionados();
               $('.cupones_bienvenida_todos .cupon_check').attr('disabled', true);
            }

        });
```

**Lista No.2**
Es basicamente la misma forma de ir aumentando la cantidad de producto.

```
$$('.lista_productos_elegir3').on('click','.sumarProducto3', function(e){
        var list3                         = $(this).closest('.swipeout_productos3');
        var el_product_quantity_producto3 = list3.find('.product-quantity');
        var tipo_material                 = list3.find('.tipo_material').text();
        var tipo_costo_material           = list3.find('.tipo_costo_material').text();
        var codinv_material               = list3.find('.codInventario_material').text();
        var preciosocio_material          = list3.find('.preciosocio_material').text();
        var volumenNegocio_material       = list3.find('.volumenNegocio_material').text();
        var tipo_seleccion                = list3.find('.tipo_seleccion').text();
            product_sum                   = parseInt(el_product_quantity_producto3.text());
            cantidad_suma                 = product_sum+1;


        var cantidad_valor3 =0;
        var lista3;
        $('.lista_productos_elegir3 li').each(function(e){
            lista3 = $(this).find('.product-quantity');
            cantidad_valor3 += parseInt(lista3.text());
        });

        if (cantidad_valor3 >=3){
           myApp.alert("Puede llevar un máximo de 3 productos");
           el_product_quantity_producto3.text(el_product_quantity_producto3.text());
        }
        else{
            $(".lista_productos_seleccionado > tr").remove();
            productos_seleccionados = deleteItem(productos_seleccionados, codinv_material);

            productos_seleccionados.push({
                "codigo": codinv_material,
                "precio": preciosocio_material,
                "cantidad": cantidad_suma
             })
           el_product_quantity_producto3.text(cantidad_suma);
           agregarCupon(idPedido, codinv_material, tipo_costo_material, preciosocio_material, volumenNegocio_material, cantidad_suma, cod_cliente, tipo_cliente,cod_cupon, parseInt(tipo_seleccion));
           productosSeleccionados();
           $('.cupones_bienvenida_todos .cupon_check').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
```

Como puedo hacer si en la **Lista No. 1** ya llevo un producto seleccionado ya no me permita seleccionar ningun valor de la *Lista No. 2* y viceversa

Comment: `cantidad_suma` almacena la cantidad de productos de manera global? si es así lo que puedes hacer es cancelar el evento `click` o mostrar una alerta justo antes de toda la lógica que tienes `$$('.lista_productos_elegir3').on('click','.sumarProducto3', function(e){ if(cantidad_suma == 1){return false // aqui cancelas el evento}`

Comment: esa variable no es global, lleva el contador por cada lista.

Comment: la variable cantidad_valorN, es declarada por cada lista?

Comment: si exacto Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la variables 'cantidad_valor1', 'cantidad_valor2', 'cantidad_valor3' colócalos como variables globales, sácalos del evento click y los declaras en la parte superior de tu código y los inicializas en 0. Ahora dentro de cada evento realiza una condición para validar si ya existe un valor en alguna de las variables a validar:

```
$('.lista_productos_elegir').on('click','.sumarProducto1', function(e){

    if(cantidad_valor2 <= 0 && cantidad_valor3 <=0){

        var list = $(this).closest('.swipeout_productos1');
        var el_product_quantity_producto1 = list.find('.product-quantity');
        var tipo_material                 = list.find('.tipo_material').text();
        var tipo_costo_material           = list.find('.tipo_costo_material').text();
        var codinv_material               = list.find('.codInventario_material').text();
        var preciosocio_material          = list.find('.preciosocio_material').text();
        var volumenNegocio_material       = list.find('.volumenNegocio_material').text();
        var tipo_seleccion                = list.find('.tipo_seleccion').text();
            product_sum                   = parseInt(el_product_quantity_producto1.text());
            cantidad_suma                 = product_sum+1;
            //el_product_quantity_producto1.text(cantidad_suma);
        var lista;
        $('.lista_productos_elegir li').each(function(e){
            lista = $(this).find('.product-quantity');
            cantidad_valor1 += parseInt(lista.text());
        });

        if (cantidad_valor1 >=1){
           myApp.alert("Puede llevar un máximo de 1 productos");
           el_product_quantity_producto1.text(el_product_quantity_producto1.text());
        }
        else{
            $(".lista_productos_seleccionado > tr").remove();
            productos_seleccionados = deleteItem(productos_seleccionados, codinv_material);

             productos_seleccionados.push({
                "codigo": codinv_material,
                "precio": preciosocio_material,
                "cantidad": cantidad_suma
             })
           el_product_quantity_producto1.text(cantidad_suma);
           agregarCupon(idPedido, codinv_material, tipo_costo_material,preciosocio_material,volumenNegocio_material,cantidad_suma,cod_cliente,tipo_cliente,cod_cupon,parseInt(tipo_seleccion));
           productosSeleccionados();
           $('.cupones_bienvenida_todos .cupon_check').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }else{
        console.log("No puedes agregar mas productos a esta lista.");
    }

});
```

Recuerda quitar dentro del evento, donde declaras la variable que colocaste ya como global.

Y así hazlo por cada evento. Espero que haya entendido y que haya podido ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Pudieras en el click de cada una desabilitar el click de la otra usando unbind de la siguiente forma

```
$('.lista_productos_elegir').on('click','.sumarProducto1', function(e){
    $( ".lista_productos_elegir3").unbind( "click" ); 
    ........
```

y lo mismo en la otra lista

**EDITADO**
Para manejar el click de forma diferente en la otra lista se puede asignar nuevamente despues del unbind

```
$('.lista_productos_elegir').on('click','.sumarProducto1', function(e){
  $( ".lista_productos_elegir3").unbind( "click" ); 
  $(".lista_productos_elegir3").on('click','.sumarProducto3',function(e){ 
    alert("solo se puede seleccionar productos de una lista"));
   });
```

Comment: y como podria mostrarle una alerta al usuario por que motivo no puede darle seleccionar un producto de esa lista?

Comment: Edite la respuesta para que veas como puedes quitar el click de agregar producto y poner un click que muestre un alert. aqui puedes alertar de la forma que entiendas con modal etc...